What is the best way to use dataLayer custom variable in Google tag manager for sales tracking in google ads
My gtm script is already setup. and dataLayer push is also working fine.
But cant able to get value of transcationId, currency & transcationTotal in google tag manager on order completed page of our website
I have tried via javascript, html hidden field id & custom javascript as well but never worked.
My dataLayer variable is defined like this:

Here is google ads conversion tracking variable configured

Here is dataLayer array with values in console on order completed page:

Getting result like this:

I have tried so many ways like:

dataLayer.currency
dataLayer[0].currency
currency
window.dataLayer[0].currency
etc

but no luck :(

Keep in mind that any JavaScript variable (like dataLayer) will not exist when you navigate to a new page.

@James, thank you for the comment. I know that our script defined on order completed page itself and dataLayer also pushing on same page.

If you console log dataLayer do you see your needed values?

Yes and i've already shared screenshot in my question. Can you take a look ?

Right - how/where are you attempting to retrieve these values, because if you enter dataLayer[0].currency in the console right after dataLayer, I imagine it works.

currency in datalayer variable should work. Can you share more on how you set in the google ads tag and how you check it is not working. From the current screenshot can not tell that.

@James yes i have tried with many ways but no luck so far.. not sure how google is fetching from dataLayer

@darrelltw I have added one more screenshot for google ads conversion tracking now you will have more idea pls check

https://imgur.com/a/rEUVOlB Do you change the output to value and check? Default it will shows the variable name.

@darrelltw Thanks!. You are right i wasn't able to see that option in my screen until i click event and now i saw the values.. but i placed two order but conversion not tracked or increased in google ads goal purchase event.. any clue?
